# WPF setting keyboard-focus without code behind at runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I searched a lot on that topic but couldnt really find a solution for this using no code behind. I know some would say using code-behind for this view related things is totally ok, but nevertheless i would like to avoid it.

I have a usercontrol which shows a "dialog" with a single textbox and an OK button. That dialog is a simple usercontrol that is placed on top of all others. By default the usercontrols visibility is set to collapsed. I would like to set the keyboardfocus to the textbox on the dialog usercontrol if the usercontrol gets visible. Is there any way to do this completely in xaml? Since my dialog-control is not visible at the time when the control is loaded, simply setting

`FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=tbID}"`

will not work. I tried to use some kind of visibility trigger:

```
   <TextBox Grid.Column="3"
             Grid.Row="5"
             Name="tbID"
             VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                        <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=tbID}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

but this doesnt work either. The trigger gets fired but the textbox doesnt get the focus. I would really appreciate any suggestions on that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to bind to the `UserControl` `Visibility` property not the `TextBox`

Example

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication7.IconButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="200" Name="_this">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="tbID" Margin="0,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=tbID}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: This is the soultion! I changed **_this** in your code to the name of my usercontrol and it works great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using an attached behavior to set the focus. Here's some sample code:

```
public static class Focus
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShouldFocusWhenVisibleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ShouldFocusWhenVisible", typeof (bool), typeof (Focus), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), ShouldFocusWhenVisibleChanged));

    private static void ShouldFocusWhenVisibleChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uiElement = sender as UIElement;
        if (uiElement == null) return;

        var shouldFocus = GetShouldFocusWhenVisible(uiElement);
        if (shouldFocus)
        {
            UpdateFocus(uiElement);
            uiElement.IsVisibleChanged += UiElementOnIsVisibleChanged;
        }
        else
            uiElement.IsVisibleChanged -= UiElementOnIsVisibleChanged;
    }

    private static void UiElementOnIsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uiElement = sender as UIElement;
        if (uiElement == null) return;

        UpdateFocus(uiElement);
    }

    private static void UpdateFocus(UIElement uiElement)
    {
        if (!uiElement.IsVisible) return;

        Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.Focus(uiElement);
    }

    public static void SetShouldFocusWhenVisible(UIElement uiElement, bool value)
    {
        uiElement.SetValue(ShouldFocusWhenVisibleProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetShouldFocusWhenVisible(UIElement uiElement)
    {
        return (bool)uiElement.GetValue(ShouldFocusWhenVisibleProperty);
    }
}
```

Then, you apply the following code to the TextBox in your dialog: `<TextBox local:Focus.ShouldFocusWhenVisible="True" />`. Note that `local:` will need to be a reference to the namespace of the Focus class above.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! this is also a good way to handle what i was looking for.